# Can I invoke the continuity of eigenvalues to prove this result?

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, singular-values

Suppose I have two sequences $(A_n)$, $(B_n)$ of $n\times n$ symmetric real matrices (growing sizes) such that $||A_n-B_n||_F\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, where $||\cdot||_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm. I want to show that

$$|\lambda_i(A_n)-\lambda_i(B_n)|\to 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{as} \hspace{1cm}n \to \infty$$ where $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$th largest eigenvalue.

My first instinct was to invoke the continuity of eigenvalues on the space of real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. Indeed using Gershgorin's Theorem one can show that for any two such matrices $A$,$B$ we have

$$|\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_i(B)|\leq n||A-B||_F$$

The problem is that $n$ is growing here, and  so $n||A_n-B_n||_F$ may not be a null sequence.

As an alternative I thought about using Weyl's inequalities:

$$\lambda_i(B_n)+\lambda_n(A_n-B_n) \leq \lambda_i(A_n)\leq \lambda_i(B_n)+\lambda_1(A_n-B_n)$$

or

$$\lambda_n(A_n-B_n) \leq \lambda_i(A_n)-\lambda_i(B_n)\leq \lambda_1(A_n-B_n) \hspace{1cm} (*)$$

Now, because $A_n-B_n$ is real symmetric, its singular values are the absolute values of its eigenvalues. Furthermore, the largest singular value of $A_n-B_n$ (spectral norm) is dominated by the Frobenius norm, i.e. $\sigma_1(A_n-B_n)\leq ||A_n-B_n||_F$. Hence the LHS and RHS of $(*)$ both converge to zero as $n\to \infty$. The desired result follows.

Is this correct?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your second argument works perfectly well

Comment: Correct. But the result holds for any matrix, not necessarily symmetric. $A$ is continuous in its coefficients, hence also its characteristic polynomial, and thus its roots.